# Creating the "Push Up Game" in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to recreate the push up playing card game in android sdk. For those who are unfamiliar, the push up game is where you draw a card from a deck of normal playing cards and, based on the suit and rank, you have to perform a set of a certain kind of push up. For example, drawing a 5 of diamonds would require you to complete 5 diamond style(hands closed together) push ups. The suit and corresponding push up type are listed as follows: 
Heart - Regular 
Diamond - Diamond
Club - Staggered 
Spade - Wide arm 
(you can read more about the game over here: http://www.nexercise.com/2012/12/fitness-game-the-push-up-game/)

I have yet to implement images of the playing cards so, for now, I am just trying to get the text to display properly.  Basically, once the app starts, I want the user to be able to push the button to generate a new card which will then print a message on the screen stating the number and type of push ups to be completed by the user.

Anyway, here is the code I've worked on so far:

```
public class Card {

public enum Suit {
    HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES
}
public enum Rank {
    ACE, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, JACK, QUEEN, KING
}
public enum PushUp {
    REGULAR, DIAMOND, STAGGERED, WIDEARMED
}

private Suit mSuit;
private Rank mRank;
private PushUp mPushUp;

public Card(Suit mSuit, Rank mRank, PushUp mPushUp) {
    this.mSuit = mSuit;
    this.mRank = mRank;
    this.mPushUp = mPushUp;
}

public Suit getSuit() {
    return mSuit;
}

public void setSuit(Suit suit) {
    mSuit = suit;
}

public void setRank(Rank rank) {
    mRank = rank;
}

public void setPushUp(PushUp pushUp) {
    mPushUp = pushUp;
}

public Rank getRank() {
    return mRank;
}

public PushUp getPushUpType() {
    return mPushUp;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Card:" + mRank.name() + "of" + mSuit.name() + "/n" +
            "Complete:" + mRank.name() + "of" + mPushUp.name() + "push ups.";
}
```

The card class uses 3 different enums(suit, rank, push up type) to create the card object. The class has a toString method to convert the card information into a string.

```
public class Deck {
private Card[] deck;

public Deck() {
    this.deck = new Card[52];
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
        for (Card.Suit s : Card.Suit.values())
            for (Card.PushUp p : Card.PushUp.values())
                for (Card.Rank r : Card.Rank.values()) {
                    Card c = new Card(s, r, p);
                    this.deck[i] = c;
                }
}
public Card pickACard() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(this.deck.length);
    Card card = this.deck[randomNumber];
    return card;

}
public String setText() {
    String text = pickACard().toString();
    return text;
}
```

}

The deck class creates an array filled with all the different cards. The deck class has a method to draw a random card and a method to pull the text from that random card.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mButton;
private TextView mTextView;
private Deck mNewDeck;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = "";
            text = mNewDeck.setText();
            mTextView.setText(text);

        }
    };
    mButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

}

the main activity class is the main screen that pops up when the app starts. it has a button and a text view. The button should generate a new card and new string every time it's pressed.

When I try to run the app in the emulator, I get the following error:

> Blockquote
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.aman.pushupgame, PID: 3325
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual >method 'java.lang.String com.example.aman.pushupgame.Deck.setText()' on a null >object reference
>                                                                                  at com.example.aman.pushupgame.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)

My biggest concern at the moment is getting the code to run as I'm not sure how to fix this error. I am fairly new to both java and android and I am doing this project as a learning experience to reinforce the concepts I have learned thus far. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `NullPointerException` being thrown at line 29 of your code. It looks to me your line (don't have line numbers)

```
text = mNewDeck.setText();
```

is the problem. You never instantiate it, thus it's null and throwing this error.

You need to call `mNewDeck = new Deck()` somewhere (like onCreate() method) before you can use setText() method from the Deck class.